# PHP redirect on exact date

Tags: php, date, redirect

I'm using this code to redirect based on the hour of the day, and the day of the week.

Here it is ..

```
<?php

$hour = date('G');
$minute = date('i');
$day = date('w');
$m = $hour * 60 + $minute; // Minutes since midnight.

if (
  $day == 0    // Sunday...
  && $m >= 615 // ... after 10:15…
  && $m <= 700 // ... but before 11:40…
) {
  header("Location: open.php");
}
else
if (
  $day == 3     // Wednesday...
  && $m >= 1125 // ... after 18:45…
  && $m <= 1235 // ... but before 20:35…
) {
  header("Location: open.php");
}

?>
```

I was wondering if there was a way to redirect to a page based on an exact date in the future like April 25th or November 1st.

Thanks .

Comment: So you only want to redirect if it's at those times on a specific day to 'open.php'?  Or if it's those specific times or that specific day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple approach, which does not take account the year date:

```
// 25th april:
if (date('d') == '25' && date('m') == '4') {
  header('Location: open.php');
}
// 1st nov:
if (date('d') == '1' && date('m') == '11') {
  header('Location: open.php');
}
```

Look at the [date() documentation](http://php.net/date) for more exact details.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the redirection date into timestamp using `strtotime()` or `date()` and you can do it easily

```
if(strtotime("2012/5/3") <= time()) {
     header("location: toredirect.php");
     exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure.

```
$date = date();
$redirectDate = Date here;

if($date == $redirectDate) {
    header("Location: open.php");
}
```

This is going to be based on your server date/time